# Java schedule a job to run at certain time for maximum period of time

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to schedule a task that should run every 10 seconds. However this task should have a dynamical allowed period execution time. In other words, if the max allowed time is 5 seconds and if the task runs for more than 5 secs it should be killed/shutdown.

I have tried to use `@Schedule` with a cron time but no matter what I try I can't kill once it is running.  However, an advice was given to me to not use the `@Schedule` and create a normal task with a `ScheduledExecutorService` but I have no idea how to do it.

My original method looks like that:

```
    @Scheduled(cron = "0/10 * * * * ?")
    @Transactional
    public void testMethod(Integer period) {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler;

        scheduler.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(period);
        scheduler.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(false);

        importantMethod();
        
    }
```

I have tried to rewrite it like so:

```
public void testMethod(){
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);            
  scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(importantMethod(), delay,
                                  period, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

However, I'm not sure how to set it up to have no delay to run every 10 seconds or every 5 mins and to only shut it down after the maximum allowed time is exceeded.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As per the description, my assumptions:

1. Task should run every 10 seconds
2. Task should have maximum time-out of 5 seconds
3. Max time-out should be configurable

configuration in *application.properties*

```
scheduler.timeout = 5000
```

Code

```
    @Value("${scheduler.timeout}")
    private Long timeout;
    
    @Scheduled(cron = "0/10 * * * * ?")
    public void taskScheduler() {
        System.out.println("Task Started: " + LocalDateTime.now());
        this.executeTask((Callable<Object>) () -> {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(3000);//Change values for testing: sleep time
            System.out.println("Task Worked: " + LocalDateTime.now());
            return true;
        }, timeout);
    }
    
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    ScheduledExecutorService canceller = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    
    public <T> Future<T> executeTask(Callable<T> c, long timeoutMS) {
        final Future<T> future = service.submit(c);
        canceller.schedule(() -> {
            if (!future.isDone())
                System.out.println("Task Cancelled: " + LocalDateTime.now());
            future.cancel(true);
            return "done";
        }, timeoutMS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        return future;
    }
```

Output
When task completed in 3 seconds (sleep time)

```
Task Started: 2022-02-06T22:42:30.010704200
Task Worked: 2022-02-06T22:42:33.014775100
```

When task completes in 6 seconds (sleep time)

```
Task Started: 2022-02-06T22:47:30.003249500
Task Cancelled: 2022-02-06T22:47:35.013195900
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the best way to do it, but here is a working way i came up with.

You would need three types of tasks:

1. the task itself, which has to run periodically - the important task
2. another task which will cancel it's execution, i'll call it kill task from now on.
3. task to submit the important task for execution - the submit task, this is what you will schedule with the `ScheduledExecutorService` to run periodically

The idea is, when your important task starts execution, it will schedule the kill task to run 5 seconds later. In order to achieve that, it needs to know its' [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) instance. And for that, it needs the submit task to do the submission and let it know of its' `Future`.

Here is `important task`:

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ImportantTask implements Runnable {

    //that's just to make it easier to track what happens with each task
    private static long NEXT_ID = 1;

    //needed to schedule kill task
    private final ScheduledExecutorService executorService;
    private final long taskId;
    private Future<?> thisTaskFuture;
    //only needed to know when to cancel all tasks and end test
    private CountDownLatch countDownLatch;

    public ImportantTask(ScheduledExecutorService executorService) {
        this.executorService = executorService;
        this.taskId = NEXT_ID++;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //make half the tasks take too long
        long executionTimeSeconds = this.taskId % 2 == 0 ? 6 : 4;
        System.out.println(this.getLogMessage("started"));

        CancelFutureTask cancelFutureTask = new CancelFutureTask(this.thisTaskFuture);
        //this schedules the kill task for single execution, after 5 seconds delay
        this.executorService.schedule(cancelFutureTask, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        try {
            //simulating long execution
            Thread.sleep(executionTimeSeconds * 1_000);
        } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
            System.out.println(this.getLogMessage("interrupted"));
            //might need to check Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted(), depends on your exact case
            return;
        } finally {
            this.countDownLatch.countDown();
        }
        //the task is already finished, even if cancel is called, it has no effect
        System.out.println(this.getLogMessage("finished"));
    }

    private String getLogMessage(String taskStatus) {
        return String.format("Task with id - %d, %s at %s", this.taskId, taskStatus, LocalTime.now());
    }

    public void setThisTaskFuture(Future<?> thisTaskFuture) {
        this.thisTaskFuture = thisTaskFuture;
    }

    public void setCountDownLatch(CountDownLatch countDownLatch) {
        this.countDownLatch = countDownLatch;
    }
}
```

The [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) is here only to make it easier to stop main method after few executions, you probably do not need it. Take note of the comments in the code.

The `kill task` is quite simple:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class CancelFutureTask implements Runnable {

    private final Future<?> future;
    private final boolean mayInterrupt;

    public CancelFutureTask(Future<?> future, boolean mayInterrupt) {
        this.future = future;
        this.mayInterrupt = mayInterrupt;
    }

    public CancelFutureTask(Future<?> future) {
        this(future, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.future.cancel(this.mayInterrupt);
    }
}
```

It just cancels a `Future` and will have no effect if the future has already finished execution.

And `submit task`:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;

public class SubmitNewImportantTask implements Runnable {

    private final ScheduledExecutorService executorService;
    private final CountDownLatch countDownLatch;

    public SubmitNewImportantTask(ScheduledExecutorService executorService, CountDownLatch countDownLatch) {
        this.executorService = executorService;
        this.countDownLatch = countDownLatch;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ImportantTask importantTask = new ImportantTask(this.executorService);
        //obtain Future instance
        Future<?> future = this.executorService.submit(importantTask);
        //let the task know of its Future instance
        importantTask.setThisTaskFuture(future);
        importantTask.setCountDownLatch(this.countDownLatch);
    }
}
```

It submits `important task` for execution, obtains the `Future` instance and sets it in `important task`.

And the main method i used for testing.

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class FuturesMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CountDownLatch count = new CountDownLatch(6);
        ScheduledExecutorService executorService = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(10);
        SubmitNewImportantTask submitTask = new SubmitNewImportantTask(executorService, count);
        executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(submitTask, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        count.await();
        executorService.shutdown();
        boolean allTerminated = executorService.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("All terminated - " + allTerminated);
    }
}
```